# Angular ui-router templateProvider never called

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to pass a route parameter to the server responding with a template, so I'm trying to use a `templateProvider` per several articles/other stack overflow docs.

I'm not getting any javascript errors, but the following `templateProvider` method is never even executed. When the `templateUrl` property is not commented out, this route works fine.

```
$stateProvider
.state('org.contacts.add', {
  url: '/add',
  views: {
    'org@': {
      // templateUrl: '/templates/issues/add',
      controller: 'ContactsAddController',
      templateProvider: function($route, $templateCache, $http) {
          var url = '/templates/' + $route.current.params.org + '/contacts/add';
          $http.get(url, {cache: $templateCache}).then(function(html){
              return html;
          });
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

After some experimentation, it seems the `$route` was causing trouble. Taking that out and using `$stateParams` at least fires this code/controller.

However, while I see the ajax call firing and the proper html response, it's never loaded to the view.

```
    templateProvider: function ($stateParams, $http, $templateCache) {
        var url = '/templates/contacts/add';
        $http.get(url, {cache: $templateCache}).then(function(html){
            return html;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to return a `$promise` for this to work. Check out the example used on the [UI-Router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki):

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts', {
  templateProvider: function ($timeout, $stateParams) {
    return $timeout(function () {
      return '<h1>' + $stateParams.contactId + '</h1>'
    }, 100);
  }
})
```

Notice the line that begins with `return $timeout(...`.  Have you tried returning the `$promise` that is created by doing `$http.get()`?

Comment: This helped me realize that by taking out `$route`, and using `$stateParams`, I'm at least getting the route to apply and the controller to load. I'm now seeing almost everything work - the http request is made, the params are right, yet the HTML response is never loaded into my view. I'll update my question with the new code

Comment: Returning the http promise directly just injects `[object Object]` into the view.

Comment: Yay, solved it. Looking at the source for angular ui-router itself, this is what they used: `return $http.get(url, {cache: $templateCache }).then(function(response){return response.data;});`