# Angular Ui-Router TemplateProvider Never Called Despite Returning A Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

This question is similar to this: [Angular ui-router templateProvider never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345020/angular-ui-router-templateprovider-never-called) except in my case I *am* returning a promise and it still isn't working. The xhr request is never fired.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

      // For any unmatched url, send to /content
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/content")

      $stateProvider.state('map1', {
           url: "/content/sectionI",
           templateProvider: function($http, $stateParams) {
            return $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: '/contentMore',
              params: {request:"Section_I_Unlocked",part:"map"}
                }).then(function successCallback (html){
                    return html.data;
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

What am I doing wrong? I see the url change when I click on state `map1` but the templateProvider never fires?

Comment: Does the state work if you use `template`? I'm not sure it has anything to do with `templateProvider`. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EnywFh1Ht4v7ecK238l5?p=preview)

I adjusted a bit the *url* path *(but mostly for plunker purposes, not sure how your server is configured)*, and the concept as is is working:

```
  $stateProvider.state('map1', {
    url: "/content/sectionI",
    templateProvider: function($http, $stateParams) {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'contentMore.html',
        params: {
          request: "Section_I_Unlocked",
          part: "map"
        }
      }).then(function successCallback(html) {
        return html.data;
      });
    }
  });
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EnywFh1Ht4v7ecK238l5?p=preview)

There are even more easy ways how to load data.. e.g. with combination **`templateProvider`** and **`$templateRequest`**:

#### [Using templateRequest in angular + typescript ($templateRequest not a function)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33123850/1679310)

#### [Angular ui.router reload parent templateProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29785692/1679310)

Comment: Well it's the `url` parameter, my server is using Laravel as a backend so the url is `contentMore` not `contentMore.html` so I will have to figure out how to fix that.